# How to convert Matrix to a type Mat?

Tags: c#, matrix, mat, emgucv

I am using EmguCV to do simple image processing. I want to remove small contours from my thresholded image so I used **connectedcomponentswithstats**. Below is my code where I convert any pixel smaller than the minimum size into black - essentially deleting it. The reason I want to do this is to be able to use it in the latter part since it is not compatible with other types.

```
public Mat Filtered(Mat in_img, string currentDir)
{
    Mat gray_res = new Mat();
    Mat labels = new Mat();
    Mat stats = new Mat();
    Mat centroids = new Mat();

    CvInvoke.CvtColor(in_img, gray_res, ColorConversion.Bgr2Gray);

    var nlabels = CvInvoke.ConnectedComponentsWithStats(gray_res, labels, stats, centroids, LineType.EightConnected);

    int min_size = 250;

    int[] sizes = new int[nlabels];

    for (int s = 1; s < nlabels; s++)
    {
        sizes[s] = BitConverter.ToInt32(stats.GetData(s, (int)ConnectedComponentsTypes.Area), 0);
    }

    Matrix<double> fltr_img = new Matrix<double>(labels.Rows, labels.Cols);
    fltr_img.SetValue(0);

    for (int i = 1; i < nlabels; i++)
    {
        int j = BitConverter.ToInt32(stats.GetData(i, (int)ConnectedComponentsTypes.Left), 0); //left most
        int w = BitConverter.ToInt32(stats.GetData(i, (int)ConnectedComponentsTypes.Width), 0); //run width
        int k = BitConverter.ToInt32(stats.GetData(i, (int)ConnectedComponentsTypes.Top), 0); //top most
        int h = BitConverter.ToInt32(stats.GetData(i, (int)ConnectedComponentsTypes.Height), 0); //run height

        if (sizes[i] < min_size)
        {
            for (int a = k; a < k + h; a++)
            {
                for (int b = j; b < j + w; b++)
                {
                    fltr_img.Data[a, b] = 255;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Covnert 2D Matrix to Image
    CvInvoke.Imwrite(currentDir + "filter.jpg", fltr_img);

    Mat subtrahend = CvInvoke.Imread(currentDir + "filter.jpg");

    Mat fnl_img = new Mat();

    CvInvoke.Subtract(in_img, subtrahend, fnl_img);

    return fnl_img;
}
```

What I did, in the end, is a little dirty trick to convert the mask into a compatible type **Mat** which is the original image. With this code, I am getting my result but I am still bothered by it.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert Matrix type by using its Mat property. I don't know what type you need so I used DepthType.Cv8U in my example.

```
Mat converted = new Mat();
fltr_img.Mat.ConvertTo(converted, DepthType.Cv8U);
Mat fnl_img = new Mat();
CvInvoke.Subtract(in_img, converted, fnl_img);
```

Alternatively, you can also use Mat and/or Matrix together with substract method. Both implement  IInpurArray interface.

```
CvInvoke.Subtract(in_img,  fltr_img, fnl_img); //Tested with EmguCv 3.4.1
```

Comment: It doesn't work. What I want is to convert the Matrix<> format (which I used to create the filter as seen in the for loop above) into a something compatible with the Mat format (which I used to load the image) so that I can use EmguCV subtract to get the desired result.

Comment: Matrix and Mat can be both used in CvInvoke.Subtract(IInputArray src1, IInputArray src2, IOutputArray dst) without compilation errors as both implement IInputArray interface. I tested it with EmguCV 3.4.1. So i do not understand why you have to convert Matrix to Mat.

Comment: When I used your code. It throws this exception ---> Exception thrown: 'Emgu.CV.Util.CvException' in Emgu.CV.World.dll

Comment: Does the exception provides more detailed information?